# iOS Multiple file uploading to server using NSURLSessionTask

Tags: ios, afnetworking, nsurlsession, nsurlsessiondownloadtask, nsurlsessionuploadtask

I'd like to upload lots of files to server. for instance, the user taken images more than 50 when not reachable on network and hit send button. Then i should upload them when reachable on network. iOS doesn't allows to add session task with large size post request when not reachable on network. so i've tried a chained tasks. but it's takes very long time to wakeup next task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no limitation for requests in iOS. You can send data with arbitrary length to a server. But, for large data you should avoid loading the complete data into memory. Instead you should setting `HTTPBodyStream` in `NSMutableURLRequest` or a file (e.g. `uploadTaskWithRequest:fromFile:completionHandler:`).

Comment: @Priya https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38349943/background-upload-multiple-images-using-single-nsurlsession-uploadtaskwithreques